# Creating clean url from a post

Tags: php

I am using THE PERFECT PHP CLEAN URL GENERATOR from http://cubiq.org/the-perfect-php-clean-url-generator

```
public static function create($clean, $delimiter='-') {
    echo $clean;
    $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $clean);
    $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
    $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
    $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);
    echo $clean;
    return $clean;
}
```

to clean a name field being posted from a form now for some reason when I set the clean varible to `“Hi! I’m the title of your page!”` it gives me back `hi-im-the-title-of-your-page` which is to be expected but if I grab the clean variable from a post it goes in as `“Hi! I’m the title of your page!”` but comes out as `hi-i039m-the-title-of-your-page` is there anyway to fix this? Is there something I am not understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your code the string is html encoded which turns ’ to #039; then at following step

```
$clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
```

characters # and ; are stripped and you end up with 039

Comment: I dont understand if this is the case, then why does it work when I just declare $clean to be “Hi! I’m the title of your page!”

Comment: html encoding is done outside of this function, when you set clean in function preg_replace replaces all non alphanumerical chars as usual so it works.